# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$router'), what is this error about? How can I fix this?

Tags: vue.js, redirect, error-handling, router

`$`Happy New Year! So, I'm setting up a redirect after an authentication token retrieval and I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$router')" in the console and the user is not redirected to the desired page ("/dashboard"). I'm outsourcing the authentication to a dataRequests.user.js file that then goes to a vue component. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```c
import common from "./dataRequests.commons";
import { login, inputLogin, inputPassword } from '/src/pages/Index.vue'

let userRequest  = {}


userRequest.authenticate = (inputLogin, inputPassword) => {
      
    return new Promise(() => {
      let axios = require("axios");
      
      let config = {
      method: 'post',
      baseURL: common.baseURL + '/auth/login',
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      },
      data : {
        login: inputLogin,
        password: inputPassword,
      }

    };
    
    axios(config)  
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .then(() => this.$router.push(this.$router.redirect || '/dashboard'))
    
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      //console.log('input login', this.inputLogin)
      //console.log('input password', this.inputPassword)
    });
    
    console.log('input login', inputLogin)
    console.log('input password', inputPassword)
      
    });        
}



export default userRequest;
```

Comment: Why do you think `this.$router` should refer to a router? What do you think `this` will refer to here…?

Comment: I'm new to vue so I don't really understand what this. is meant to call (other than the route in question, like a "self" in other languages I suppose). it's just the syntax I found online and it worked in the vue component. What I don't understand is why is it not working when I I outsource the auth function. I've tried without it and I still get an error, except it marks "ReferenceError: $router is not defined" instead.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I figured a work-around for this (I forgot to say I'm working with Quasar.js too): Apparently vue.js doesn't like to use vue router outside of .vue components (at least without messing around with router/routes.js), so, I did a loop-like cycle between the .vue component and the dataRequests.js file. I first send the fields as exports in the setup() as input ref(), import them in dataRequests, do the promise inside it and then export the result into the .vue component and call it in the methods {} section inside <script></script> section.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import common from "./dataRequests.commons";
import { login, inputLogin, inputPassword } from '/src/pages/Index.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from 'router'

let config = {
      method: 'post',
      baseURL: common.baseURL + '/auth/login',
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
}

userRequest.authenticate = (inputLogin, inputPassword) => {
      
      const apiClient = axios.create(config)
       
      return new Promise(() => {
          apiClient.post(data : {
            login: inputLogin,
            password: inputPassword,
        })
        .then(() => router.push...etc
```